# External custom domain to render from an app without change the URI in the address bar of the browser

Tags: nginx, hosting, subdomain

The following works for `any_subdomain.mydomain.com` meaning from the app code I can detect the request URI and serve the page accordingly while `any_subdomain.mydomain.com` stays in the browser address bar:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^www\.(?<subdomain>.+\.)?mydomain\.com$;
    return 301 "$scheme://${subdomain}mydomain.com$request_uri";
}
```

Now I tried the following for `customer_domain.com` expecting to land at `mydomain.com` while keeping `customer_domain.com` in the browser address bar, but in reality it changes the URI in address bar and my app code cannot distinguish it from `mydomain.com`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(.+\.mydomain\.com)(?<domain>)?$;
    return 301 "$scheme://${domain}mydomain.com$request_uri";
}
```

The following block forwards to the app.

```
server {
    listen  80 default_server;
    server_name ~^.+\.mydomain\.com$ mydomain.com;

    location / {
        # omitted. serve contents.
    }
}
```

In all cases, sub/domains are mapped using A records. CNAME is not an option. Can you help me with what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The server block you've posted doesn't seem to have anything to do with routing any_subdomain.mydomain.com to the actual webapp. All it does is remove the 'www' prefix when there is one (in other words the purpose of this config _literally is_ to change the URI in address bar). Please edit the post and show the actual server block that runs the webapp.

Comment: That RegEx matches all subdomains except www, because when trying to match and serve subdomains we should ignore www. When matches, I have another server block which is not relevant here that serves the contents of `mydomain.com` as you can see from 301.

The second block, however, tries to match any domain except the subdomains of `mydomain.com`, but fails I believe.

Comment: No it doesn't; there is nothing in that regex that says "except www". It specifically _only_ matches domains starting with `www.`

Comment: I am having hard time agreeing with you on this, but I have added the final `server` block in the post.

Comment: From what you've posted, the webserver configuration _as a whole_ is meant to handle all subdomains while ignoring the 'www' part. But the way it is implemented is that the first server block _specifically_ catches all subdomains starting with 'www.' and redirects the user to the non-www version (rewriting the URL bar), and _then_ the new request hits the second block and runs the app.

Answer (score 1):

`return 301` is an HTTP redirect. HTTP 30x redirects are responses sent to the web browser, so they *always* change what's shown in the address bar, because that's literally what they do.

For example, your first server{} block [matches](https://regex101.com/r/EfCbT1/3) `www.(something).mydomain.com` and rewrites the URL in order to remove the 'www' prefix, resulting in just `(something).mydomain.com` shown in browser's the address bar.

And that's the only thing the first block does. After that happens, the "real" webapp requests aren't matched by the first block – they're matched by the final block.

So in order to allow the webapp to run on domains other than "mydomain.com", do not use a 301 redirect for anything; just add them to this line:

```
server_name ~^.+\.mydomain\.com$ mydomain.com;
```

Use a 301 redirect **only** if you want to implement the "www"-removal, or otherwise change the URL visible in the address bar.

**Example configuration**

```
# strip 'www' from our own domain & subdomains
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^www\.(?<subdomain>.+\.)?mydomain\.com$;
    return 301 "$scheme://${subdomain}mydomain.com$request_uri";
}

# strip 'www' from customer's domain & subdomains
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^www\.(?<subdomain>.+\.)?customer\.com$;
    return 301 "$scheme://${subdomain}customer\.com$request_uri";
}

# serve the webapp for all domains that didn't match the above redirects
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name ~^.+\.mydomain\.com$ mydomain.com
                ~^.+\.customer\.com$ customer.com;

    location / {
        # omitted. serve contents.
    }
}
```

---

How the domains are mapped is not important: neither the web browser nor the web server are aware of the distinction between A and CNAME and do not change their behavior; both kinds of domains eventually resolve to the same IP address either way.